# How to disable google managed prom?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, google-managed-prometheus

I enabled managed service for prom in GCP console

It installed bunch of agents with gmp-system namespace on my gke cluster

how do I uninstall it?

i tried kubectl delete all --all -n gmp-system

but it just respawns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a managed add-on, you need to [disable](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/update#--disable-managed-prometheus) it via `gcloud`:

`gcloud container clusters update --disable-managed-prometheus ${CLUSTER_NAME}`